# Replace two strings with each other vb.net

Tags: css, .net, vb.net

i need to replace two strings in rich text box with each others

for example:

padding: 12px **22px** 33px **0px**;

i want to replace "**22**" with "**0**"
and "**0**" for "**22**"

to be like this one:

padding: 12px **0px** 33px **22px**;

Note: these two numbers are not always 22 & 0, they are variables

Comment: is the format of the string always same??

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: yes it's always like that, and yes i've tried so many codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it !

Thanks to Markus code, i merged his code after some changes with substring and it works perfectly !

```
For Each lne In RichTextBox1.Lines
        If lne.Contains("padding") Then
            Dim code As String = lne
            Dim del As String = code.Substring(code.IndexOf("padding") + 8)
            Dim padding As String = del
            Dim split As List(Of String) = padding.Split(" "c).ToList   'split padding String by spaces
            Dim nd As String = split(2)
            Dim rth As String = split(4)
            split(2) = rth    'replace 22px with 0px
            split(4) = nd 'replace 0px; with 22px;
            Dim newPadding As String = String.Join(" "c, split.ToArray)
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

this might get you started:

```
Dim padding As String = "padding: 12px 22px 33px 0px;"

Dim split As List(Of String) = padding.Split(" "c).ToList   'split padding String by spaces

split(2) = "0px"   'replace 22px with 0px
split(4) = "22px;" 'replace 0px; with 22px;

Dim newPadding As String = String.Join(" "c, split.ToArray)

Console.WriteLine(newPadding)
```

Comment: that code works only with numbers "22 & 0" .. but the numbers 12, 22, 33 and 0 are not always the same
they change every time

Comment: thats why i said it will get you started, SO is not a code writing platform

Answer (score 0):

Following swap method will work only if your input string format is always same.Should have equal number of white spaces between each items and number of items in string is limited to `5` .

```
Dim input As String = "padding: 12px 22px 33px 0px;"
Dim arinput As String() = input.Split(" ")
Dim val As String
val = arinput(2)
arinput(2) = arinput(4).ToString.Replace(";", "")
arinput(4) = val & ";"
Dim output As String = String.Join(" ", arinput)
```

---

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QMakBO)

Comment: if you swap them just like that you will have to take in account that the ";" is now at the wrong place